# LIMIT keyword on MySQL with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, limit

```
SELECT id, content, date
FROM comment
WHERE post = ?
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT ?, ?
```

With PDO (I'm using MAMP 2.0.5 that has Apache 2.2.21, PHP up to 5.3.6, and MySQL 5.5.9) prepared statement this doesn't work, if I change the query with

```
LIMIT 0, 10
```

it works.

I see in the bugs of MySQL that this was a bug in previous version but I can't understand if this is still to be fixed.

If this is still a problem, there is a way to select a range of rows in another way?

code:

```
$comments = $db->prepare($query); 
/* where $db is the PDO object */ 
$comments->execute(array($post, $min, $max));
```

Comment: How do you bind your parameters?

Comment: Work around would be to cast the values that you are substituting into the `LIMIT` clause to `(int)` and specify them literally in the query. This is a sanitisation step that cannot be circumvented in such a way that it breaks anything, any string that is not a valid integer representation will result in `0`. Worst case scenario, you get no results.

Comment: $comments = $db->prepare($query); /* where $db is the PDO object */ $comments->execute(array($post, $min, $max));

Comment: no error in PHP code or anything else, echo $db->errorInfo(); shows "Array"

Comment: to echo an array one have to use a loop. or a `var_dump()` at least.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
$comments = $db->prepare($query); 
/* where $db is the PDO object */ 
$comments->execute(array($post, $min, $max));
```

The manual page for [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) says (emphasis mine):

> **Parameters**
>
> `input_parameters` An array of values with as many elements as there are
>   bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. **All values are
>   treated as PDO::PARAM_STR**.

Thus your parameters are getting inserted as strings, so the final SQL code looks like this:

```
LIMIT '0', '10'
```

This is a particular case where MySQL will not cast to number but trigger a parse error:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 LIMIT 0, 10;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 1 LIMIT '0', '10';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '10'' at line 1
```

What [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm140469743390096) have to say:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows
>   returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric
>   arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with
>   these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Your choices include:

- Bind parameters one by one so you can set a type:

  ```
  $comments->bindParam(1, $post, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $comments->bindParam(2, $min, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $comments->bindParam(3, $min, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  ```
- Do not pass those values as parameters:

  ```
  $query = sprintf('SELECT id, content, date
      FROM comment
      WHERE post = ?
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT %d, %d', $min, $max);
  ```
- Disable emulated prepares (the MySQL driver has a bug/feature that will make it quote numeric arguments):

  ```
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
  ```

Comment: Great explanation defused all my anger at the error thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a specific attribute to resolve the problem.

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

The other answer illustrates how it works. PDO just emulates prepares by default, and as you are binding your variables silently, without setting a type, PDO treats them as strings by default. Strings in SQL have to be quoted and escaped - thus you have quotes in your LIMIT clause and a syntax error. While when native prepared statements are used, a database can manage to sort out the appropriate type.

Comment: the other answer illustrates how it works. PDO just emulate prepares by default, and as you are binding your variables silently, without setting type, PDO treats them as strings by default. Strings in SQL have to be quoted and escaped - thus you have quotes in your LIMIT clause and a syntax error. While when native prepared statements used, a database can sort the things out.