# Prepared statement limit not working even with emulate prepares turned off

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My query

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM generalevent ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, 25');
$stmt->execute(array( $limit ));
```

keeps failing with the message

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: 
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, 25' at line 1' 
in ../test.php:35 
Stack trace: #0 ../test.php(35): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM g...') #1 {main}
```

I already have

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

so from what I have read, this should work, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while using PDO prepared statements and LIMIT in query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738451/error-while-using-pdo-prepared-statements-and-limit-in-query)

Comment: How is `$limit` being defined?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$limit = $currPage*25;` Its type is `integer`, I checked with `gettype`.

Comment: If `$currPage` is a string (which I assume stands for "current page"), then try using double quotes instead `("SELECT * FROM generalevent ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, 25")`

Comment: Yet I tend to think that using `$currPage*25` is invalid, since `LIMIT` only (*usually*) accepts a single integer and not a mathematical equation; *I think*. @gta0004

Comment: @Fred-ii- both `currPage` and `limit` are integers though

Comment: @Fred-ii- If I put $limit right in the query like `'SELECT * FROM generalevent ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT '.$limit.', 25'` it works

Comment: You're getting the error on the `prepare` and not on the `execute`? Is the code that you posted the exact code that you're running?

Comment: You may need to bind them then. @gta0004

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried binding it like this: `$stmt->bindValue(1, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->execute(); ` but it still throws the same error message. Even if I add a cast to integer.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes and Yes

Comment: Just for fun, try putting `date` in backticks (since it is a reserved word).

Comment: @PatrickQ I still get the same error.

Comment: @PatrickQ FYI: [`date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is not a reserved word.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, you are correct.  It is a "keyword", not a "reserved word".

Comment: @gta0004 Can you try `$stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);` Or `DESC LIMIT %d, 25'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nothing changes with bindValue. It works with %d, but isn't that the same as inserting the value directly into the query with `.$limit.` ?

Comment: I don't know. I only found that in the Q&A (and comments) here http://stackoverflow.com/q/7772648/ @gta0004 I'd have to further test it later on if I have any free time.

Comment: Using %d is not the same as using a bound variable or parameter, but provides some of the same benefits especially with regard to SQL Injection.  It forces whatever is inserted into the query to be a numeric value and not some unintended statement.  However, it will still defeat the query cache as a different query will be submitted depending on the supplied parameter, where a properly parametrized query will not.

Comment: You can also try adding `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` which (to a certain degree) worked for me while using `LIMIT ?,25` and `LIMIT :limit,25` then binding that afterwards. @gta0004 - However, I am very limited to testing, since you haven't provided full code.

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below @gta0004

Comment: Try using `"`s instead of `'`s in query

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me, however it's hard to give a definite answer, since full code was not provided.

Here is what I tested with, on my own server from an existing table.

**Sidenote:** Using `:limit` or `?` after `LIMIT` both worked and did not throw any errors.

```
<?php
$mysql_username = 'xxx'; // for DB
$mysql_password = 'xxx'; // for DB

try {

$pdo= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     exit( $e->getMessage() );
}

try {

$currPage = 2;

// $limit = 1;

$limit = $currPage * 25;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM animals LIMIT :limit,25";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

     $results = $pdo->query($sql);

//     print_r($results);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
}

    $cols = $results->columnCount(); // Number of returned columns

    echo 'Number of returned columns: '. $cols. '<br />';

echo '

<div align="center">
  <center>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>

      <td width="10%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><p align="center">ID</td>
      <td width="33%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><p align="center">Breed</td>
      <td width="34%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><p align="center">Species</td>
    </tr>

';

foreach($results as $row) {

echo "<tr><td width=\"10%\"><p align=\"center\">" . $row['id'] . "</td>\n<td width=\"33%\">" . $row['name'] . "</td><td width=\"33%\">" . $row['species'] . "</td>";

}

echo "\n";
  echo "</tr>";

echo '

  </table>
  </center>
</div>
';

?>
```