# Fatal error with prepared query in php/sql

Tags: php, sql

I am coding in php using XAMPP on Windows. `$bdd` is a variable obtained with:

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=memviv', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

If I execute the following query I have no problems:

```
$res_query = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM cards WHERE due < NOW() AND (state = \'default\' OR state = \'recover\') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50');
```

However, if I execute a similar, prepared query where I inject a positive integer `$n_card` as the value of the LIMIT:

```
$res_query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM cards WHERE due < NOW() AND (state = \'default\' OR state = \'recover\') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?');
$res_query->execute(array($n_cards));
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''50'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\memviv\php\include\study_functions.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\memviv\php\include\study_functions.php(14): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\memviv\php\study_model.php(71): compute_review_queue_db(50) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\memviv\php\study_model.php(34): new_queue('review', 50) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\memviv\php\study.php(5): study_model() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\memviv\php\include\study_functions.php on line 14
```

Could you help me solve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738451/error-while-using-pdo-prepared-statements-and-limit-in-query

Comment: Thank you, I would never have thought the error to be so specific.