# Is there a way to specify a start point for a SELECT database query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I understand how `LIMIT` works, but I want to know if there is a way to set the starting point for a database query before `LIMIT`. Is this possible? And am I making sense with this?

Comment: @ wordman can you explain it clearly...

Comment: Well, I'd like to specify a starting point in the table to begin counting from...does that make any more sense?

Comment: @wordman `tell the query where to start selecting BEFORE it gets to LIMIT` why? it is much better to include sample records and desired result on your question to make it more clearer to the readers.

Comment: @wordman an example would help understanding the actual question

Comment: @JW, I understand that. What I am asking here is if this is even possible. So in other words, can we tell the query to start at row 5, for instance, then from there select all records equal to `red` and limit the result to 27 records?

Comment: how about this simple example? [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15e92/2) It uses subquery.

Comment: @JW Thank you for that. Tell me, in the subquery, what if I wanted to change the numbers in `LIMIT 3, 7` to variables such as `$offset` and `$limit`. What would the proper syntax be for that?

Comment: use PreparedStatements, [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [limit keyword on MySQL with prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014147/limit-keyword-on-mysql-with-prepared-statement-maybe-still-a-bug)

Comment: @JW Yes, I am utilizing prepared statements in my code. Would it be possible for you to show me the proper syntax for inserting the variables Imentioned as they are? It would help me understand things more at the moment.

Comment: create a query like this `SELECT * FROM ....... WHERE ..... LIMIT :x, :y` see the link i gave you `:D`

Comment: @JW Thanks, but I'm not getting any of that. I was looking for more specific info. I appreciate it though, I'll leep researching this elsewhere.

Comment: @JW I just worked on my code with your subquery suggestion and IT WORKS exactly as I wanted. How can I give you credit here for this answer? Thank you!

Comment: @wordman great to hear that. i just updated the answer with the fiddle. `:D`

Comment: @wordman to give JW credit, simply click that check mark next to his answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIMIT` accepts two values, the starting point and the duration.

- [MySQL LIMIT *X, Y*](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

**UPDATE 1**

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15e92/2)

Comment: what do you mean by duration?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT [offset], [count]
```

So say you had 4 pages (1, 2, 3, and 4), and wanted to show 10 results per page you would do something like:

**page_1 (0 - 10)**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT  0, 10
```

**page_2 (10 - 20)**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 10, 10
```

**page_3 (20 - 30)**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 20, 10
```

**page_4 (30 - 40)**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 30, 10
```

Comment: now that is intriguing and almost exactly what I was looking for earlier. I need some clarification on the `page_1 >>` things.

Comment: Sorry, that was just to show "which page we were on". I edited it to be more clear.

Comment: Okay...that makes some more sense...let me chew on that...thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT [startpoint], [row_count]
```

Where start point is optional and is default to the first row. Specifying the start point skips the record n-times and starts counting at [startpoint]

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 5, 15
```

That will display 15 records starting from the 5th record.

`SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 7` is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 0,7`

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a demo learn from this

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but I will give it a shot.  You may want to look into using variable binding in your query, this way your limit is set with variables. Code example using PDO below:

```
class englishTable {
  private $selectAllWithLimit;

  public function __construct($db) {
    $this->selectWithLimit = $db->prepare('SELECT id, english, french FROM english LIMIT :start, :limit');

  public function selectWithLimit($start, $limit) {
    $this->selectWithLimit->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $this->selectWithLimit->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $this->selectWithLimit->execute();
    return $this->selectWithLimit->fetchAll();
  }
}

$start = 5;
$limit = 7;
$words = $englishTable->selectWithLimit($start, $limit);
```

Hope this helps, happy new-year friend.

Comment: I appreciate that! However, I am asking if the starting point can be set BEFORE WE GET TO `LIMIT`?

Comment: I realise I did not understand. Limit clause takes 1 0r 2 parameters. If you set this in a variable (as is commonly done), and you set your variables before executing the sql, in this manner would you not agree  your limit parameters are set before the limit is called?

Comment: This post was exploratory but it led me to two solutions, one of which is marked as the answer above. I was asking for something different that obviously caused a lot of confusion, but it inadvertently led to two solutions for me. Many thanks!