# Binding number to the LIMIT of a PDO query with PHP

Tags: php, pdo, limit, bind

I am having an issue with PDO which I have seen discussed around but the different solutions provided did not work for me. It is when binding a number to set the LIMIT of a SQL query.

Here is the error I get:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 1 in ...
```

The code:

```
$remaining = 3 - $countRows;
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
$result4 = $con->prepare("SELECT  * FROM  item_descr WHERE id_item != ? LIMIT ?");
$result4->execute(array($itemId, intval($remaining)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

Adding this line and removing the `intval(` was the solution, as suggested here:

[Answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014147/limit-keyword-on-mysql-with-prepared-statement-maybe-still-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do something like:

```
SELECT  * FROM  item_descr WHERE id_item != :id LIMIT :limit

$result->bindParam(':id', $itemID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(':limit', $remainint, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

with your current code you are not really binding parameters.

Comment: This does not work: Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in