# PDO error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm getting this annoying error and although I have an idea of why I'm getting it, I can't for the life of me find a solution to it.

```
if ($limit) {
   $sth->bindValue(':page', $page - 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sth->bindValue(':entries_per_page', $page * $entries_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$sth->execute($criteria);
```

Query contains placeholders (`:placeholder`). But to add those LIMIT placeholders, I need to use the manual method (`bindValue`) because otherwise the engine will turn them into strings.

I'm not getting the Invalid number of parameters error, so all placeholders have been bound correctly (I assume).

Query:

```
SELECT `articles`.*, `regional_municipalities`.`name` AS `regional_municipality_name`, 
       `_atc_codes`.`code` AS `atc_code`, `_atc_codes`.`name` AS `substance`
FROM `articles`
LEFT JOIN `_atc_codes`
ON (`_atc_codes`.`id` = `articles`.`atc_code`)
JOIN `regional_municipalities`
ON (`regional_municipalities`.`id` = `articles`.`regional_municipality`)
WHERE TRUE AND `articles`.`strength` = :strength
GROUP BY `articles`.`id`
ORDER BY `articles`.`id`
LIMIT :page, :entries_per_page
```

All placeholder values reside in $criteria, except for the last two LIMIT, which I manually bind with `bindValue()`.

Comment: Try to search in google "PDO binding LIMIT parameters"

Comment: 1) It would've been nice to include the human readable error message instead of just the cryptic code, 2) Show your actual query so we can see where the error stems from.

Comment: @deceze If there was any human readable message in there, I'd: a) probably solved it by now, b) if not, then included it here. This was the full error message, trust me.

Comment: Error: 2031 (CR_PARAMS_NOT_BOUND)Message: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement FROM Documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-client.html

Comment: @davidstrachan Do you know why my PHP version does not return that "human readable error message"?

Comment: Sure you're binding `:strength` as well? Sure `$limit` is truthy?

Comment: @deceze Yeah, `$criteria` only contains one value: `'strength' => string '1g' (length=2)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot use `->bind*` *and* `->execute($params)`. Use either or; if you pass parameters to `execute()`, those will make PDO forget the parameters already bound via `->bind*`.

Answer (score 30):

This same error 2031 can be issued when one bind two values with the same parameter name, like in:

- `$sth->bindValue(':colour', 'blue');`
- `$sth->bindValue(':colour', 'red');`

..so, beware.

Comment: This answer saved my day!

Comment: You saved my day. I changed the parameter name as.. ':colour0', 'colour1', 'colour2' ... . and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 20):

This exception also appears if you try to run a *query* with placeholders instead of *preparing* a statment such as

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID > ?');
```

instead of

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ID > ?');
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> `public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )`
>
> Execute the prepared statement. If the prepared statement included
>   parameter markers, you must **either**:
>
> - call PDOStatement::bindParam() to bind PHP variables to the parameter markers: bound variables pass their value as input and
>     receive the output value, if any, of their associated parameter
>     markers
> - or pass an array of input-only parameter values

You need to pick a method. You cannot mix both.

Comment: I can't use `bindParam`/`bindValue` for the other values...sigh.

Comment: @silkfire Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014147/limit-keyword-on-mysql-with-prepared-statement-maybe-still-a-bug/10014200#10014200 for other ideas.

Comment: `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true)` - shouldn't that **enable** emulated prepares? I think it's the other way around though, very misleading.

Comment: @silkfire - That's for spotting the typo, I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly an answer, but this error also happens if you try to use a word with a hyphen as placeholders, for example:

`$sth->bindValue(':page-1', $page1);`

So better use

`$sth->bindValue(':page_1', $page1);`

Answer (score 1):

The exception also happens (at least in MySQL/PDO) when your SQL tries to UPDATE an AUTO_INCREMENT field.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted Roadowl's answer. The reality for the error is that it's very generic.

Comment: Not only is the error message very generic, I just caused that message with exactly the circumstance described.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you have mismatching parameters. For example:

```
$q = $db->prepare("select :a, :b");
$q->execute([":a"=>"a"]);
```