# Laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
$pois = Home::select(\DB::raw('*, st_distance_sphere(homes.geopoint, point(?, ?)) as dist'))
    ->whereRaw('st_within(homes.geopoint, ST_Buffer(point(?, ?), 1))')
    ->orderBy('dist')
    ->get();
```

returns `Laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031` However this query below works

```
$pois = Home::selectRaw('*, st_distance_sphere(homes.geopoint, point('.$data["lng"].', '.$data["lat"].')) as dist')
    ->whereRaw('st_within(homes.geopoint, ST_Buffer(point('.$data['lng'].', '.$data['lat'].'), 1))')
    ->orderBy('dist')
    ->get();
```

but it is vulnerable to SQLInjection. I've done the suggestions mentioned in stackoverflow. [PDO error: General error: 2031 [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337984/pdo-error-general-error-2031)

Comment: have you tried DB::table(<table_name>)->select(DB::raw(<query>))

Comment: I want to do it with model. Isn't it possible?

Comment: It probably is possible, you've got a rather specific query, and I don't have a Laravel instance to play with right now. But query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect against SQL injection. If you need to set specific bindings you can use `setBindings()` method to not create injection points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectRaw and whereRaw allow you to use placeholders and pass an array of values as the second argument:

```
selectRaw('*, st_distance_sphere(homes.geopoint, point(?, ?)) as dist', [$data['lng'], $data['lat']])
```

Comment: It returned `strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: On the selectRaw?  Are either of the values of $data['lng'] and $data['lat'] arrays?  I'm not sure why strtolower would even be called here.  The raw methods are documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: yes i'm sure about that. I have `dd` it was an string.

Comment: I just don't see a strtolower error being caused by selectRaw, it seems unrelated.  If you think it's related, post an update with a backtrace in your question.