# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make an insert in the `gynecology` table, this table has no rows.

[Table Gynecology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfaeF.png)

the session variable is 2 in another page.

```
$_SESSION ["id_patient"] = 2;


<?php
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO gynecology(id_patient, nvisita, date_visit, background, reason_visit, exploration, exploration_comp, diagnosis, treatment) 
                                        SELECT IFNULL(gy.id_patient,:id_patient), IFNULL(max(gy.nvisita),0)+1, (now()), :background, :reason_visit, :exploration, :exploration_comp, :diagnosis, :treatment
                                        FROM gynecology gy, patients pa
                                        WHERE gy.id_patient = pa.id
                                        AND PA.ID = :id_patient");

                $insert->bindParam(":background", $background);
                $insert->bindParam(":reason_visit", $reason_visit);
                $insert->bindParam(":exploration", $exploration);
                $insert->bindParam(":exploration_comp", $exploration_comp);
                $insert->bindParam(":diagnosis", $diagnosis);
                $insert->bindParam(":treatment", $treatment);
                $insert->bindParam(":id_patient", $_SESSION["id_patient"]);

                $insert->execute();         
    ?>
```

The `patients` table contains the id of the patient.

thanks.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: It fails to make the insert:Query failedSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: You have less `bindParam()` than the real `:params`  you have in query. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missmatching parameters. Change with this:

```
            $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO gynecology(id_patient, nvisita, date_visit, background, reason_visit, exploration, exploration_comp, diagnosis, treatment) 
                                    SELECT IFNULL(gy.id_patient,:id_patient), IFNULL(max(gy.nvisita),0)+1, (now()), :background, :reason_visit, :exploration, :exploration_comp, :diagnosis, :treatment
                                    FROM gynecology gy, patients pa
                                    WHERE gy.id_patient = pa.id
                                    AND PA.ID = :id_patient");

            // this first parameter is missing
            $insert->bindParam(":id_patient", $_SESSION["id_patient"]); 
            // the other parameters you have
            $insert->bindParam(":background", $background);
            $insert->bindParam(":reason_visit", $reason_visit);
            $insert->bindParam(":exploration", $exploration);
            $insert->bindParam(":exploration_comp", $exploration_comp);
            $insert->bindParam(":diagnosis", $diagnosis);
            $insert->bindParam(":treatment", $treatment);
            $insert->bindParam(":id_patient", $_SESSION["id_patient"]);
```

Comment: What is supposed to do with this comment?

Comment: Please, tell us if this answer solves your problem, and if yes, upvote and check it as correct answer. Thank you :)

Comment: This error is generated: Query failedSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Comment: Try removing `$insert->execute()`. It seems that `bind[*]()` and `execute()` can't be mixed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274556/pdo-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2031

Comment: If you do not inform the WHERE clause if it works but I need to reference the patient id

Comment: Háblame en español si quieres, porque no te entiendo. No sé qué es lo que me intentas decir aunque creo que mi respuesta ya te puede ayudar a solventar el problema

Comment: Gracias!! Básicamente necesito hacer un INSERT en la tabla 'gynecology' la cual puede tener muchos registro por cada paciente.

En caso de que el paciente no tenga ninguna visita, creará la primera sin embargo, si el paciente ya tiene alguna visita le sumará 1 a la última visita registrada.

En la tabla 'patients' está la información de los pacientes con un id para identificarlos.

Comment: Cuando intento insertar una nueva visita para un paciente que ya ha tenido una visita, lo hace correctamente.

Pero cuando intento insertar una nueva visita para un paciente que no tiene ninguna, me sale el error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Perdona por mi inglés chapurrero.

Comment: El error `invalid parameter number`  es lo que te explico en la respuesta. Simplemente, falta el primer parámetro de la query que es `id_patient`. Añadiendo eso este error se va. Pero me cuentas que cuando añades esto te sale el error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031` el cual significa que estás mezclando funciones `bindParam()` y `execute()`(más info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274556/pdo-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2031 )

Comment: Lo siento, ha sido un error tonto, pero me has ayudado!
Muchas gracias por tu interés.

Yo pensaba que podía reutilizar 

 <pre>$insert->bindParam(":id_patient", $_SESSION["id_patient"]);   </pre>

En más de un apartado del INSERT.

Comment: Suena lógico, pero PDO necesita que le especifiques los parámetros en orden y todos bien presentados. Si tienes algún otro problema avísame! Por cierto, puedo recomendarte stackoverflow en español: http://es.stackoverflow.com Un saludo!

Comment: genial, muchas gracias :)