# PHP Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create my own CMS... I am working on displaying pages...
I do it by parsing url and depending on it I determine whether it will be a blog post or normal page...

```
private function parsujURL($url)
{
    $naparsovanaURL = parse_url($url);
    $naparsovanaURL["path"] = ltrim($naparsovanaURL["path"], "/");
    $naparsovanaURL["path"] = trim($naparsovanaURL["path"]);

    if (strpos($naparsovanaURL["path"], "/") !== false)
        $rozdelenaCesta = explode("/", $naparsovanaURL["path"]);
    else
        $rozdelenaCesta = array($naparsovanaURL["path"]);

    return $rozdelenaCesta;
}
public function zpracuj($parametry)
{
    $naparsovanaURL = $this->parsujURL($parametry[0]);

    if(empty($naparsovanaURL[0]))
        $this->presmeruj('clanek/uvod');
    // kontroler je 1. parametr URL
    $tridaKontroleru = $this->pomlckyDoVelbloudiNotace(array_shift($naparsovanaURL)) . 'Kontroler';

    if (file_exists('kontrolery/' . $tridaKontroleru . '.php'))
        $this->kontroler = new $tridaKontroleru;
    elseif (SpravceStranek::dotazNaStranku($naparsovanaURL)>0)
        $this->kontroler = new StrankyKontroler();
    else
        $this->presmeruj('chyba');
    //Volání kontroleru
$this->kontroler->zpracuj($naparsovanaURL);
```

But when I type localhost/onas (about us page(as it should be)) it just shows up error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Modely\Db.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Modely\Db.php(23): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Modely\SpravceStranek.php(43): Db::dotazJeden('SELECT `stranka...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Kontrolery\SmerovacKontroler.php(42): SpravceStranek::dotazNaStranku(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(21): SmerovacKontroler->zpracuj(Array) #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Modely\Db.php on line 23
```

This is refering to these lines... more specific to line with execute...

```
    public static function dotazJeden($dotaz, $parametry = array())
{
    $navrat = self::$spojeni->prepare($dotaz);
    $navrat->execute($parametry);
    return $navrat->fetch();
}
```

`$dotaz` would be request in English. And `$parametry` would be parameters.
Eg. function for returning pages

```
    public function vratStranku($url) // Translation: public function returnPage($url)
{

    return Db::dotazJeden('SELECT `stranka_id`, `titulek`, `obsah`, `url`, `popisek`, `klicova_slova` FROM `stranky` WHERE `url` = ? ', array($url));
// Translation: return Db::requestOne('SELECT `page_id`, `title`, `content`, `url`, `description`, `key_words` FROM `pages` WHERE `url` = ? ', array($url))
}
```

So $dotaz is

```
'SELECT `page_id`, `title`, `content`, `url`, `description`, `key_words` 
FROM `pages` WHERE `url` = ? '`
```

and $parametry is `array($url)`

Sorry for not having my program in English but it is not my mother tongue so I don´t use it...

Does anyone know what the error means or why is it occuring?

Comment: What is the contents of `$dotaz` and `$parametry`? Seems you have mismatching variables... Please update your question

Comment: Dupe? `bind` **or** `execute`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274556/pdo-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2031

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you are right, I misread that prepare statement. Agreed.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I hope my brief explanation will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array_shift was changing the url so it didn´t work.

Solution:

```
      public function zpracuj($parametry)
{
    $naparsovanaURL = $this->parsujURL($parametry[0]);

    $naparsovanaURL2 = $naparsovanaURL;

    if(empty($naparsovanaURL[0]))
        $this->presmeruj('clanek/uvod');
    // kontroler je 1. parametr URL
    $tridaKontroleru = $this->pomlckyDoVelbloudiNotace(array_shift($naparsovanaURL2)) . 'Kontroler';

    if (file_exists('kontrolery/' . $tridaKontroleru . '.php')){
         $this->kontroler = new $tridaKontroleru;
        $naparsovanaURL = $naparsovanaURL2;
    }

    elseif (SpravceStranek::dotazNaStranku($naparsovanaURL)>0) {
        $this->kontroler = new StrankyKontroler();
```