# SQL Query with Limit using prepared Statement PDO (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am really new to PDO, but I need to use it to avoid SQL injections.

Here is my SQL Query with the variables I've got via the POST Request and I want to do a PDO with that SQL Query (this version works):

```
if($refid == "") $refid="%";

$lastOrders = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE REFID LIKE'$refid' 
               ORDER BY dateAdded DESC LIMIT 0,$limiter";
$ps_orders = $db->query($lastOrders);
$data = $ps_orders->fetchAll();
```

My problem(s): The given $refid is either a number which I can find in the database, or it isn't specified by the POST Request (so the value is $refid="") and in that case I want to set the WHERE part to this: WHERE REFID LIKE '%', so I can see in that case all results for every "RefID". Is there a way to do it that way, or do I really need to create 2 different SQL Queries for both cases ?

My try:

```
if($refid == "") $refid="%";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE REFID LIKE ':refid'
ORDER BY dateAdded DESC LIMIT :min,:max";
$ps_orders = $db->prepare($sql);
$ps_orders->bindParam(':refid', $refid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ps_orders->bindParam(':min', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ps_orders->bindParam(':max', $limiter, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: Why use PDO without prepared statements..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014147/limit-keyword-on-mysql-with-prepared-statement-maybe-still-a-bug

Comment: $ps_orders->bindParam(':min', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ps_orders->bindParam(':max', (int)$limiter, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: It is still not working. How can I remove this stupid duplicated mark ?! -.-

Comment: You're using `':refid'` in your SQL string. You don't need to quote your placeholders like that - the database will take care of that for you when you prepare the data. You might want to explain - what do you mean when you say this isn't working? Do you get a syntax error from the PHP? An error from the database? Do you get the wrong data? Some of the right data?