# Which is better, using intval() or sprintf('%d')?

Tags: php, printf

I am looking for good answer which is best to use between intval() and sprintf('%d') especially on sanitizing unwanted characters?

```
$offset = '12';
$max = '100';

function getOffsetLimit($offset, $max = 100) 
{
   $offset = intval($offset);
   $max = intval($max);

   $sql = " LIMIT $offset, $max";
   return $sql
}
```

or

```
function getOffsetLimit($offset, $max = 100) 
{
   $sql = sprintf(" LIMIT %d, %d", $offset, $max);
   return $sql
}
```

--

Thanks,

camsy

Comment: Don't do either of these. Use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: Neither: [LIMIT keyword on MySQL with prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014147/limit-keyword-on-mysql-with-prepared-statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: check with regex for exact characters you allow instead

Comment: @Andrew - Using regex for this would be extreme overkill. Just because you _can_ do something with regex doesn't mean it's a good idea. `LIMIT` only allows integers which you can handle very well without regex. However, as others have mentioned, all that is the wrong path either way.

Comment: hello, i am dealing with legacy codes as of the moment. assuming i cannot use prepared statement, give the sample codes above, which one is better? thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this then be the perfect time to refactor the code so you can use it?

Comment: You should put every effort into upgrading from PHP4 (assuming this is the reason you can't use prepared statements) and moving away from concatenated SQL queries.

Comment: would take ages to do it... the whole system using legacy mysql_query() functions... estimated will take 5 years to do that and will kill the business. somehow, we are on the process of refactoring, but we are under resource.

Comment: @camsy: your first sample is safe for integer escaping. You can also try `$number = (int) $string`, it's an alias for `intval` function.

Comment: @user1597430 thanks..

Comment: point is, casting user input to integer bad idea, give error and make them put in an integer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since LIMIT and OFFSET don't work with prepared statements, the next best method is to use filter_var() with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT. I think for LIMIT and OFFSET, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT should not be used.

Note that you can't have OFFSET without LIMIT in MySQL and the code below is for MySQL.

```
    function getLimitOffsetStatement($limit=null, $offset=null) {
        $sql = '';

        $filterOptions = ['options'=>['min_range' => 0]];
        if (filter_var($limit, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $filterOptions)) {
            $sql .= " LIMIT $limit";
            if (filter_var($offset, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $filterOptions)) {
                $sql .= " OFFSET $offset";
            }
        }

        return $sql;
    }
```

Comment: this is an awesome approach as well... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Neither is better. The proper solution would be to use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Note the third `$data_type` argument for `PDOStatement::bindParam()` -- that allows you to filter integers.

If you absolutely insist on building SQL with concatenated strings, then I'd use [`filter_var()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with either `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` (if you want to abort when the values aren't integers) or `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` (if you want to convert the value to a reasonable integer-like facsimile.)

Comment: yeah, "-5+3-8+7-" or "------++++++" is amazing _reasonable integer-like facsimile_

Comment: Neither `intval()` nor `printf()` works for that case either, which is why you shouldn't use any of them.

Comment: Note also that `filter_var()` supports arbitrary min/max values, allowing you to limit to positives -- which neither `intval()` nor `printf()` can do.

Answer (score 2):

They do opposite things:

- [`intval()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) converts a string to an integer.
- `sprintf('%d')` effectively converts an integer to a string.

That aside, you shouldn't use either function when dealing with SQL queries. As others have mentioned, you should be using *prepared statements*.

Comment: as of the moment, i am dealing with legacy and created a driver to handle between prepared and non-prepared statements. assuming i cannot use prepared statement, on my example, which one is better?

Comment: i don't think this is the answer.. i am dealing with legacy codes and all are still using mysql_query().

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with legacy code, then something as simple as this will work....

```
function build_sql_limit ( $total, $offset, $max = 100 )
{
    if ( ctype_digit ( $total ) )
    {
        $total = $total > $max ? $max : $total;
    }
    else
    {
        $total = $max;
    }

    if ( ! ctype_digit ( $offset ) )
    {
        $offset = NULL;
    }

    return ' LIMIT ' . ( is_null ( $offset ) ? $total : $offset . ', ' . $total );
}
```